# how do i use same sidenav in multiple pages

Tags: meteor

So i created a sidenav on one of my page and its working properly there 
what i want to do is on another page i want to use that same sidenav.

My side nav code:

```
<form id="keyword-form" class="side-nav rt-side-nav">
    <div>
        <center><h5>KEYWORDS</h5></center>
        <textarea rows="10" cols="50" id="txtarea" class="keyword-text" placeholder="enter comma seperated values for the products" contenteditable="true">{{keywords}}</textarea>                      
    </div>                      
    <div class="keyword-submit">
        <center><button type="submit" class="key-submit btn waves-effect waves-light col m12">SUBMIT</button></center>
    </div>
</form>
<a data-activates="keyword-form" class="button-collapse"></a>
<div hidden class="keyword">
</div>
```

Comment: Are you using Iron Router?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap your navbar code in a **template** then use that template on each page. See [example in the Meteor Todo app tutorial](https://www.meteor.com/tutorials/blaze/templates). Or if you are using **Iron Router** put it in your app body template.

Template example:

```
<template name="sidenav">
    <form id="keyword-form" class="side-nav rt-side-nav">
        <div>
            <center><h5>KEYWORDS</h5></center>
            <textarea rows="10" cols="50" id="txtarea" class="keyword-text" placeholder="enter comma seperated values for the products" contenteditable="true">{{keywords}}</textarea>                      
        </div>                      
        <div class="keyword-submit">
            <center><button type="submit" class="key-submit btn waves-effect waves-light col m12">SUBMIT</button></center>
        </div>
    </form>
    <a data-activates="keyword-form" class="button-collapse"></a>
    <div hidden class="keyword">
    </div>
</template>
```

Then every time you want to show your sidenav:

```
{{> sidenav}}
```